# Finding number of routes that add up to a sum in a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm

You are given a binary tree in which each node contains an integer value.

Find the number of paths that sum to a given value.

The path does not need to start or end at the root or a leaf, but it must go downwards (traveling only from parent nodes to child nodes).

```
root = [10,5,-3,3,2,null,11,3,-2,null,1], sum = 8

      10
     /  \
    5   -3
   / \    \
  3   2   11
 / \   \
3  -2   1

Return 3. The paths that sum to 8 are:

1.  5 -> 3
2.  5 -> 2 -> 1
3. -3 -> 11
```

```
class Solution {
    int count = 0;
    public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        if (root == null) return 0;
        return helper(root, sum) + helper(root.left, sum) + helper(root.right, sum);
    }
    public int helper(TreeNode root,int sum) {
        if(root == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            sum -= root.val;
            if(sum == 0) {
                return 1 + pathSum(root.left,sum) + pathSum(root.right,sum);
            } else {
                return pathSum(root.left,sum) + pathSum(root.right,sum);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

The answer is suppose to be three but my answer returns 4 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have two cases defined for your algorithm.

- **Case 1:** You are searching for a path that may exist beneath the current node.
- **Case 2:** You are searching for a path that includes the current node.

You can define `pathSum()` to follow case 1 and `helper()` to follow case 2. This way, you can use `pathSum()` to traverse the tree, and call `helper()` at any node to check for a valid path starting from that node.

```
public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root == null) return 0;
    return pathSum(root.left, sum) + pathSum(root.right, sum) //Case 1: check for sum below current node 

    + helper(root, sum); //Case 2: check for sum starting from current node
}
public int helper(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root == null) return 0;
    sum -= root.val; 
    if (sum == 0) {
        return 1; //if sum equals 0, we have a complete path, no need to go further
    }

    //else we do not have a complete path, continue searching in left and right child nodes
    return helper(root.left, sum) + pathSum(root.right, sum);
}
```